# how to change automatic placing of social plugins below content?

Tags: plugins, hooks, the-content

I'm wondering if it possible to change the automatic place below the_content() function; this is becuase I`m displaying custom information fields, but activating the social plugins which have not it´s own implementation code, the social bar or facebook commnents appears between the content and the custom fields, so important values are below the social content :/

can be created another hook to point the content of plugins? :) probably I have to modify the plugin Simple Facebook Comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-facebook-comments/) add content using `the_content` filter with a lower priority: 100.

So you can create a function that output metafields and use same filter with an higher priority, even the standard 20 priority is good.

```
function my_post_custom_data( $content ) {
  if ( ! is_single() ) return;
  global $post; 
  // here go the code that retrieve and append the custom field to the content
  // following is just an example
  $mydata = '';
  $a_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'a_key', true) ? : '';
  $another_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'another_key', true) ? : '';
  if ($a_field) $mydata .= '<li>A key: ' . $a_field . '</li>';
  if ($another_field) $mydata .= '<li>Another key: ' . $another_field. '</li>';
  $mydata = ($a_field || $another_field) ?  '<div class="myfields"><ul>' . $mydata . '</ul></div>' : '';
  // don't forget to return, at least, the content...
  return $content . $mydata;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'my_post_custom_data');
```

Comment: I tried to implement the code for this lines <br>
if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {  
  insert_audio_player("[audio:$mp3]");}

Comment: @g-m
I tried to implement the code for this lines <br />
'code'if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {  
  insert_audio_player("[audio:$mp3]");} 'code' following your example and the code of plugin and noticing the priority 100, I changed my own and, :D I got no results, sorry the 5 minutes for edit finished before typing

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar `insert_audio_player` is not a WP function. Sorry, but I've not understand what you want to do... In the question you tell only about printing some custom fields and Simple Facebook Comments plugin, nothing about audio player.

Comment: Yes, finally I could show the data above the social plugin, the problem was that the data it was showing above the main content , using the priority 20 :/ ; I have an screen of 15" and I couldn't see the full results.
Now i'm showing the player using custom field values :)